# Visual Studio project conversion

Tags: .net, visual-studio, version-control

I have a Class Library project created with VS2008 (for .net framework 3.5) that is used by several projects.

I'm starting a new project using VS2010 and I want to use this library in the new project, while keeping the VS2008 project working. Additionally I want to share the source files... that is, I don't want to have two copies of the source files. I know how to do this by creating a new project from scratch and adding the existent files as link. Is there a more automated way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same version control repository, as suggested by Joel, but create two different VS project files (e.g. `MyProject2008.csproj` and `MyProject2010.csproj`) in the same directory. (Copy the one from VS 2008 and then upgrade only the copy to 2010. Same for solution files, if required.)

The only drawback of this solution is that changes to the project structure (add files, move files, etc.) get a little cumbersome since you have to do them twice. But since VS 2008 and 2010 project files are incompatible, I don't think that you can avoid that.

Comment: I had previously marked Joel's answer as the correct one because it led me to this solution. In fact, this is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

You're using version control, right? You should be.

If you are, just check out your project from source control twice: once for each solution. This way, any changes to the code in either place can be committed back the to repository and updated/pulled in to the other.

Comment: Yes, I'm using version control. I'm not sure I fully understand your answer. VS project files are not compatible between vs2008 and vs2012, and those are also under version control.

Answer (score -1):

If you are version control, you can use [the Share operation](http://version-control.net/version-control-howto/share-command/) to share the library to the new project. This way, the modifications make on one project will be reflected to the shared one automatically.

If the library is a little different between your VS2008 and VS2010 projects, then you can use [Branch](http://version-control.net/version-control-howto/branch/). It allows you to update the source code without affecting the other copy.

Comment: -1 for reminding me of SourceSafe. Code analysis (FxCop, Resharper) will not understand the concept of shared files, it will happily note that your internal methods are not used and can be removed, without understanding that another project uses that same file and calls that internal method.